# Find consecutive series in list of tuples in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am struggling with the following issue:
I would like to write some small code to deisotope mass spec data.

For this, I compare, if the difference between two signals is equal the mass of a proton devided by the charge state. So far, so easy.

I am struggling now, to find series of more than two peaks.

I broke down the problem to having a list of tuples, and a series are n tuples, where the last number of the previous tuple is equal the first tuple of the current tuple.

From this:

[(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (7,9), (8,10), (9,11)]

To this:

[(1,2,3), (4,5), (7,9,11), (8,10)]

Simple order will fail, as there might be jumps (7-->9) and an intermediate signal (8,10)

Here is some test data:

```
import numpy as np

proton = 1.0078250319 

data = [
 (632.3197631835938, 2244.3374),  #0
 (632.830322265625, 2938.797),    #1
 (634.3308715820312, 1567.1385),  #2
 (639.3309326171875, 80601.41),   #3
 (640.3339233398438, 23759.367),  #4
 (641.3328247070312, 4771.9946),  #5
 (641.8309326171875, 2735.902),   #6
 (642.3365478515625, 4600.567),   #7
 (642.84033203125, 1311.657),     #8
 (650.34521484375, 11952.237),    #9
 (650.5, 1),                      #10 
 (650.84228515625, 10757.939),    #11
 (651.350341796875, 6324.9023),   #12
 (651.8455200195312, 1398.8452),  #13
 (654.296875, 1695.3457)]         #14

mz, i = zip(*data)

mz = np.array(mz)
i = np.array(i)

arr = np.triu(mz - mz[:, np.newaxis])

charge = 2
```

So actually, in the first step, I am just interested in the mz values. I substract all values from all values and isolate the upper triangle.

To calculate, if two signals are actually within the correct mass, I then use the following code:

```
>>> pairs = tuple(zip(*np.where(abs(arr - (proton / charge)) < 0.01)))
((0, 1), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (9, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13))
```

Now, to corresponding signals are clear by eye:

Peak 1: 0 to 1

Peak 2: 5 to 8

Peak 3: 9 to 13, without 10.

So in principle, I would like compare the 2nd value of each tuple with the first tuple of any other, to identify consequtive sequnces.

What I tried, is to flatten the list, remove duplicates and find consequtive counting in this 1D list. But this fails, as a peak from 5-9 is found.

I would like to have a vectorized solution, as this calculation is done for 100-500 signals for multiple charge states in 30000+ spectra.

I am pretty sure, this had been asked before, but was not able to find a suitable solution.

Eventually, these series are than used to check the intensity of the corresponding peaks, sum them and use the biggest initial value to assign the deisotoped peak here.

Thx
Christian

ps. also if there are some suggestion to the already existing code, I am happy to learn. I am pretty new to vectorized calculation, and usually wrote tons of for loops, which take ages to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
d = {}
pairs = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (7,9), (8,10), (9,11)]
for t in pairs:
    if t[0] in d:
       d[t[0]].append(t[1])
       d[t[1]] = d.pop(t[0])
    else:
        d[t[1]] = list(t)
signals = tuple(tuple(v) for v in d.values())
```

Though the solution isn't vectorized it will be O(n) time. Note that this solution only works if you pairs are sorted.

Answer (score 5):

In graph theory your problem will be "How to find all disconnected subgraph in a graph ?".

So why not using a network analysis library such as `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx
# Your tuples become the edges of the graph.
edge = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (7,9), (8,10), (9,11)]

# We create the graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edge)

# Use connected_components to detect the subgraphs.
d = list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

And we obtain as expected:

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {7, 9, 11}, {8, 10}]
```

With 4 subgraphs:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, I was just thinking that this could be done with an adjacency matrix.

Comment: yes connected components is the right way.

Comment: I really like this approach, but this is actually slower than O(n). See my benchmark below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses.

I really liked the networkx approach, but interestingly, this is slower then O(n) loop solution. I benchmarked both with my original data, as well as a randomized training set. In both scenarios, the results were equal (which is a prerequisite), but the O(n) solution was ~4 to 10 times faster.

Here are the benchmark

```
networkx
size: 10
22.9 µs ± 1.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 100
165 µs ± 4.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 1000
2.08 ms ± 52.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 10000
23.1 ms ± 499 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 100000
350 ms ± 6.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 1000000
4.82 s ± 120 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)

loop
size: 10
3.31 µs ± 418 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 100
35.3 µs ± 5.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 1000
350 µs ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 10000
3.95 ms ± 38.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 100000
71.6 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
size: 1000000
1.11 s ± 30.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 10 loops each)
```

[image: benchmark]

I think at very very large sample size, NetworkX might perform better, but in my scenario, small samples (< 1000 initial signals), but this very often, the loop solution wins.

And here the code to reproduce.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

def p1(edge):
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74535322/14571316
    
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edge)

    # Use connected_components to detect the subgraphs.
    d = list(nx.connected_components(G)) 
    
    return d

def p2(pairs):
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74535164/14571316 
    d = {}
    for t in pairs:
        if t[0] in d:
           d[t[0]].append(t[1])
           d[t[1]] = d.pop(t[0])
        else:
            d[t[1]] = list(t)
    signals = tuple(tuple(v) for v in d.values())
    
    return signals

print("networkx")
for size in [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    print(f'size: {size}')
    l1 = np.random.randint(0, high=int(size/2), size=size)
    l2 = np.random.randint(0, high=int(size/2), size=size)
    pairs = tuple(zip(l1, l2))
    %timeit -n10 -r2 p1(pairs)
    
print("loop")
for size in [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    print(f'size: {size}')
    l1 = np.random.randint(0, high=int(size/2), size=size)
    l2 = np.random.randint(0, high=int(size/2), size=size)
    pairs = tuple(zip(l1, l2))
    %timeit -n10 -r2 p2(pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, unfortunately not O(n) solution, but O(nlog(n)) or O(n*n) due to double cycle:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# --------------------
datain = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (7,9), (8,10), (9,11)]
dataout = [];
# ---------------------------------------------------
for ii,val_a in enumerate(datain):
    appendval = set(val_a)
    for jj,val_b in enumerate(datain[ii+1:]):
        # -------------------------------------------
        if len(set(val_a).intersection(set(val_b)))>0:
            appendval = appendval.union(val_b)
            datain.remove(val_b)
        # -------------------------------------------
    dataout.append(tuple(appendval))
# ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I tested this code, but somehow this only identifies series of up to three, but not more. But on my "wild" data, there might be more.

Comment: I do not quite understand (perhaps additional data would be good), but I guess it does not matter as well as there is already a very nice answer out here by @obchardon.

Comment: array([654.296875  , 658.35144043, 660.33404541, 662.87432861,
       663.36273193, 664.8394165 , 665.33764648, 666.83526611,
       671.34454346, 675.34649658, 675.84613037, 676.34973145,
       678.36572266, 680.37634277, 681.38269043, 682.36340332,
       683.86206055, 684.3583374 , 684.85943604, 685.36248779,
       685.8581543 , 686.34820557, 691.35180664, 692.35974121,
       692.87139893, 693.37145996, 693.8760376 , 694.37255859,
       697.35003662, 697.85821533])


The correct series would be index 17-20.
Your code reports two series
 (16, 17, 18),
 (18, 19, 20),

Comment: Well, I have hardcoded tuples with length 2 as it only checks if the first value of one matches with the others. But it should be easy to change. How do you convert the reals to the integer values so that I could try?

Comment: What happens if you replace `if val_a[1] == val_b[0]:` with `if len(set(val_a).intersection(set(val_b)))>0:` as then it checks whether there are common elements between the sets. It should be generic now for also whatever length you have for the data :)

Comment: I suggest that you also validate that `p2` gives the same answer for the same input as `p1`. `p2` expects the values to be sorted and at the moment I do not know, whether you have sorted the values or not (at least I do not see that you have done that...).